# Why dict values(list) is not iterable properly using generators in python?

Tags: python

```
D={"L1" :  [ { "a" : 10} , {"b" : 20 } ]  }
G=(y for (x,y) in L.items() ) # generator
for i in G:
    print('Hello')
    print(i)
```

iterate only once instead of twice

```
Hello [{'a': 10}, {'b': 20}]
```

same list when iterated directly, prints two elements

```
L=[ { "a" : 10} , {"b" : 20 }  ]
G=(y for y in L)
for i in G:
    print('Hello')
    print(i)

Hello {'a': 10} Hello {'b': 20}
```

Comment: It is iterating properly, there is only one key/value pair in `D`.

Comment: Is 'Y' not a list?

Comment: in the first example yes, so you `yield` `y`, so as one element. In the second example `y` is an element of `L`, so an individual dictionary.

Comment: So , how do I get to iterate that list?

Comment: The first example should be: `G=(y for y in D['L1'] )`.

Comment: `G=(y for ys in L.values() for y in ys)`.

Comment: G=(y for y in D['L1']  works good. Thank you ekhumoro.  But may I know the reason y is not treated as an multi element iterable when used in the way I used?

Comment: Because you're storing a list inside of a tuple, so when you iterate, it iterates over `([{ "a" : 10} , {"b" : 20 }])`, which is just one element... Next time, what you can do is just add `print(G)` before you iterate over it so you can see **what** it looks like and **why** they're different.

Comment: Thank you Willem , xNinjaKitty, Ekhumoro for your time.

Comment: @xNinjaKittyx. The list is inside a `dict`, not a `tuple`.

Comment: @ekhumoro `G=(y for (x,y) in L.items() )`, this stores a list inside of a tuple because it's iterating over the dict's items, which there is only 1 item (`y` would be a list)

Comment: @xNinjaKittyx. No - `G` is a generator object, not a tuple. The generator will produce one value, which is a list. I suggest you take your own advice an print the relevant objects to see what they really are ;-)

Comment: @ekhumoro ah, yes you are correct. The print result is still the same regardless. (yes there's differences in the background but that's beside the point) And touche

Comment: @xNinjaKittyx . you are right. The iterator belongs to Dictionary which naturally giving out only one value of the dict. I have to iter over value of 'i' inside the generator for loop

Comment: It is *extremely* unclear what behavior you desire. Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in g:  # when g{}
    # i is really the first key in g
    if i == 'a':
        print('True')
```

If g is a dict of lists, then you want something along the lines of

```
for key in g:
    for i in g[key]:  # g[key] is the list 'L1'
        print(i) 
        # i is an iteration in the list corresponding to the key. in this case 'L1'
```